# Django: Sending Signals - Not understanding the documentation

Tags: django

I have 2 listeners defined:

```
def update_dashbaord_modified_date(sender, **kwargs):
    """Listen for changes to Goal, Action, etc. since we
    want to update the date modified on Dashbaord when a change occurs."""
    ... do something ...

post_save.connect(update_dashbaord_modified_date) # Register to listen for post_save signals
post_delete.connect(update_dashbaord_modified_date) # Register to listen for post_delete signals
```

And now, after there is a change to a Goal or adds a Goal (model class Goal), I want that save to send a signal. How is this implemented. I don't understand the documentation for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Define your signals in your_app/signals.py (App that raise Signal, not listen)

   `from django.dispatch import Signal

    my_signal = Signal(providing_args=["instance", "args", "kwargs"])`
2. in your model/view, from where you want raise signal

   `...do some processing

    my_signal.send(sender=self.__class__, args, kwargs)

    # kwargs contains type of action, in your case

    # action= 'Added'|'Modified'|'Deleted",`
3. some where else in code (where ever you want to listen)

   `my_signal.connect(this_is_my_call_back_method)`

Answer (score 2):

From the django docs:

> Where should this code live?
>
> You can put signal handling and
>   registration code anywhere you like.
>   However, you'll need to make sure that
>   the module it's in gets imported early
>   on so that the signal handling gets
>   registered before any signals need to
>   be sent. This makes your app's
>   models.py a good place to put
>   registration of signal handlers.

You can import update_dashbaord_modified_date in you models.py and after the class definition add your method to the post_save and post_delete handlers.

```
from signals import update_dashbaord_modified_date
class myModel(models.Model):
     stuff
post_save.connect(update_dashbaord_modified_date) 
post_delete.connect(update_dashbaord_modified_date)
```

Comment: Yes, I read that in the docs. However, I don't get at which I tell the Goal model post save to send the signal. Or, do I not need to worry about that since the signal is always sent?

Comment: Correct, by default your models will always send signals for the specified event.